# Call a javascript function after new page is loaded on clicking an a href tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to call an function after a href loaded new page

```
<a title="invitation.jpg" target="_blank" class="tabmouserptr filestuffText" href="test.html?hiddenAction=viewfile&amp;fileIndex=5675568">invitation.jpg</a>
```

Javascript function need to excecute after the new page is loaded.

```
FileOpenCount() {

//stuff needed

}
```

Comment: Should the new page call the function or the current one?

Comment: @all: I need to done after the page is loaded, so 'onload' will not works. Because href goes into php part returns corresponding  result. This result want to set in  javascript function

Comment: So are you saying the desired sequence is: (1) user clicks anchor; (2) anchor loads new page in a new window; (3) after new page finishes loading a function on original page should be called? Is it good enough to call the function immediately after requesting the new page (which would be easy), or must the new page finish loading first?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, you are correct. Must the new page finish loading first.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code...
};
```

Basically you can use as above.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you could just call the function inside script tag, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FileOpenCount() {

//stuff needed

}
//call the function
window.onload=FileOpenCount;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. I think you want the original page to load something once the second page is done loading. It's not directly possible using the a tag by itself. But doing something like this might work.

```
"atag".onclick = function() {
 // open new browser window like _blank
 var win = window.open("test.html?hiddenAction=viewfile&amp;fileIndex=5675568");
 // have a reference to the new window so once it's done loading, run my function
 win.onload = FileOpenCount
};
```